# shiny fileinput r dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

Using R shiny, I am developing a simple app that allows user to input data from a file. With csv or txt files everything works fine, but I can not make R dataframes to load.

```
## SERVER.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 infile <- reactive({
 infile <- input$datafile
 if (is.null(infile)) {
  # User has not uploaded a file yet
  return(NULL)
 }
 infile<load(input$datafile$datapath) 
 })

 myData <- reactive({
   df<-infile()
   if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
 })
 output$value1 <- renderPrint({
   names(iris)
 })
 output$value2 <- renderPrint({
   names(myData())
 })
  load("iris.Rdata")   ## data loaded for testing 
})

## UI.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fileInput("datafile", label = h3("File input")),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value1"))),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value2")))
))
```

When I run this app I can see the names of the iris dataset loaded only for testing, but respect the names of the loaded file (which should be rendered as value2) only shows "NULL"

Any help?? thanks in advance!

Comment: "When I run this app I can see the names of the iris dataset loaded only for testing" why do you mean by that? Beside load("iris.Rdata") should be outside shinyServer(function(input, output) {}

Comment: to test whether the app works well, beyond file input load, I loaded IRIS dataframe, and displayed the "names". I did the same with the file input but not worked. May be is not a regular way, but I am not a programmer, so it is the way I found usefull for myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want. You had a couple of typos, and you probably didn't quite understand what `load` actually does, it loads a set of objects into memory.

I did the following things:

- added some initialization code to save a couple of .Rdata for testing, they both have exactly one object in them, a dataframe. The code needs this.
- add a line to parse out the first object in that loaded datafile and return it

Here is the code:

#### server.r

```
## SERVER.R

#Initialization
library(datasets)
save(iris,file="iris.Rdata")
save(mtcars,file="m.Rdata")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  infile <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    objectsLoaded <- load(input$datafile$name) 
    # the above returns a char vector with names of objects loaded
    df <- eval(parse(text=objectsLoaded[1])) 
    # the above finds the first object and returns it
    return(df)
  })

  myData <- reactive({
    df<-infile()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    return(df)
  })
  output$value1 <- renderPrint({
    names(iris)
  })
  output$value2 <- renderPrint({
    names(myData())
  })
  load("iris.Rdata")   ## data loaded for testing 
})
```

#### ui.r

```
## UI.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fileInput("datafile", label = h3("File input")),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value1"))),
  fluidRow(column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value2")))
))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Mike, what you did is exactly what I was looking for. **BUT**, it did not worked  for me. I copy exactly the code and run it and still can not see the names for the second df (cars). It shows NULL.
I am using R 3.2.2. shiny 0.12.2. 
Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Try clearing your session workspace first. And delete all the `*.Rdata` in your directory.

Comment: I get it working. I renamed infile for df and just worked!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you be more explicit? "renamed infile for df" is not clear to me. You renamed the `infile' function?

Comment: Ah, I found a typo. Strange how that crept in... I added a `return(df)` to the `myData` function - somehow it got deleted when I copied it over.

Comment: Mike, sorry for the delay, the following is the code that I finally get working (paste only the reactive dataframe ) :    **df <- reactive({
    df <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(df)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    objectsLoaded <- load(input$datafile$name) 
    # the above returns a char vector with names of objects loaded
    df <- eval(parse(text=objectsLoaded[1])) 
    # the above finds the first object and returns it
    df<-data.table(df)

  })**